# Spring - cannot GET resources (405 error)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Hi i have simple Spring app:

WebConfig.java:

```
package spittr.web;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spittr.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

      @Override
      public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
      }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

registerForm.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>
<%@ page session="false" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Spittr</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
          href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" >
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>registration</h1>

 <sf:form method="POST" commandName="spitter" >

      <sf:errors path="*" element="div" cssClass="errors" />

      <sf:label path="firstName" 
          cssErrorClass="error">name</sf:label>: 
        <sf:input path="firstName" cssErrorClass="error" /><br/>

         ....

      <input type="submit" value="register" />
    </sf:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and when i GET above register form with:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=GET)
  public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("spitter", new Spitter());
    return "registerForm";
  }
```

the CSS file is not loading and I get JSP page but without CSS style and with error in Tomcat console:

**127.0.0.1 - - [22/Nov/2016:18:04:48 +0100] "GET /Spittr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/resources/style.css HTTP/1.1" 405 1045**

Where is the problem? The CSS file is in the path **/Spittr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/resources/style.css** and i specified default resource handler, so why JSP page cannot get this static file.

Thanks for any advices:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i got this:

1- overriding **resourceHandlerMapping()** from **WebMvcConfigurationSupport**

```
@Override
@Bean
public HandlerMapping resourceHandlerMapping() {
    AbstractHandlerMapping handlerMapping = (AbstractHandlerMapping) super.resourceHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
    return handlerMapping;
}
```

2 - overriding **addResourceHandlers()** from **WebMvcConfigurationSupport** / **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter** :

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```